# Compound "from" clause in Linq query in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I've been working with Entity Framework for a few weeks now.  I have been working with Linq-Objects and Linq-SQL for years.  A lot of times, I like to write linq statements like this:

```
from student in db.Students
from score in student.Scores
where score > 90
select student;
```

With other forms of linq, this returns distinct students who have at least one score greater than 90.  However, in EF this query returns one student for every score greater than 90.

Does anyone know if this behavior can be replicated in unit tests?  Is it possible this is a bug in EF?

Comment: What do you mean by `other forms of linq` ? "Not linq to entities" ? This is translated to an inner join in linq to entities, so the result seems to be accurate...

Comment: Please post some sample data where you find this issue.

Comment: My example is referring to the example given in the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx).  The other forms of linq include Linq-Sql and Linq-Objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like that SQL-like syntax (I have no better name for it), especially when you start nesting them.

```
var students = db.Students.Where(student 
                                => student.Scores.Any(score => score > 90)
                                )
                         .ToList();
```

This snippet, using the method syntax, does the same thing. I find it far more readable. It's more explicit in the order of operations used.

And as far as I have experienced, EF hasn't yet shown a bug with its selection using method syntax.

**Edit**

To actually answer your problem:

```
However, in EF this query returns one student for every score greater than 90.
```

I think is is due to a JOIN statement used in the final SQL that will be run. This is why I avoid SQL-like syntax, because it becomes very hard to differentiate between what you want to *retrieve* (students) and what you want to *filter with* (scores).

Much like you would do in SQL, you are joining the data from students and scores, and then running a filtering operation on that collection. It becomes harder to then unseparate that result again into a collection of students. I think this is the main cause of your issue. It's not a *bug* per sé, but I think EF can only handle it one way.

Alternative solutions to the above:

- If it returns one student per score over 90, take the **distinct** students returned. It should be the same result set.
- Use more explicit parentheses () and formatting to nest separate SQL-like statements.

*Note: I'm not saying it can't be done with SQL-like syntax. I am well aware that most of this answer is opinion based.*